# How to solve circular structure in node js and json

Tags: json, node.js

I am developing an application with front end as angular and back end is node js, listing some values from database and send to node js .It shows some error like circular structure is there any way to override or any other option to response send back to my client side.

**Node js server instance is :**

```
app.post('/countrylist', function(req, res) {

    var urlMataData = {
        request : req,
        responce:res
    };
    amqHandler.sendToAMQPServer(serialize.serialize(urlMataData),amqpConnection, 'countrylist' ,function(err,result){
        console.log("callback value==>" + result)

    });
    amqHandler.reciveData(amqpConnection,'countrylist' ,function(err,data){
        if(!err  ){
            console.log("am reciving request")
            httpRequestHandler. makeHttpRequest(data,'countrylist', function(row){
                console.log("CountryType==>"+ JSON.parse( row));
                  //res.json(row);
            });
        } else {
            res.json(err);
        }
    });
});
```

**Request handler is :**

```
var countryList = function(req, res, next) {
query = 'SELECT id_country, country FROM edu.tbl_country';
    database.getConnection(function (err, con) {
        if(!err){
            con.query(query, function(err,row) {
                console.log("row type:"+  typeof row );
                 //res.contentType('application/json');
                 res.json(JSON.stringify(row));
            });

        }

    });


};
```

**Error**

```
var body = JSON.stringify(val, replacer, spaces);
                  ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at ServerResponse.json (/root/nodejsworkspace/EDU/rabitmq/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:228:19)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/root/nodejsworkspace/EDU/rabitmq/AMQPServer.js:116:23)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:273:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:469:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:103:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:359:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
```

Comment: Where are you using it? I mean on which object?

Comment: res.json(row) in countryList method

Comment: You're not checking for errors on `con.query()`. Also, what's the use of stringifying `row` before handing it off to `res.json()`?

Comment: Am just passing both stringfy and row, shows same error

Comment: Are you also checking for errors? What does `console.log(row)` show?

Comment: console.log(row) shows [ RowDataPacket { id_country: 1, country: 'Afghanistan' },
  RowDataPacket { id_country: 2, country: 'Albania' },
  RowDataPacket { id_country: 3, country: 'Algeria' }]

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't being caused in the callback of `amqHandler.reciveData()` (which also calls `res.json()`)? The result set looks okay to me.

Comment: Both are two server instances.